How to make an url in VBA with "&" for various params?
I have an link that based on 2 params it create an diferent report.
The problem is when i construct the link using VBA the "&" and next params just banish.
If i put this code in an cell:
=HYPERLINK("http://example.com/file.php?param1=value1&param2=value2")

if i click i get "https://example.com/file.php?param1=value1&param2=value2" at browser bar, and everything works. but if i try make a button at excel with a macro is when the problems start.
since i need an VBA macro to run an button i tried some ways to build the url but with no luck:
This on dont show "&" and next param
baseUrl = "http://example.com/file.php?"
params = "param1=value1" & "&" & "param2=value2"
url = baseUrl & params

or
This on change & with %26, and dont work.
EncodedUrl = WorksheetFunction.EncodeUrl(InputString)

the best thing i found as something like this but have some inconvinients like making a html file that opens a new tab in browser if its just to download a report file.
url = "<html><body><form id='form' action='http://example.com/file.php?' method='post'>" & _
           "<input type='hidden' name='param1' value='value1'>" & _

Im missing some way to put that & into browser without need to make an html form to get the report file?
Thank you!

The variable url contains http://example.com/file.php?param1=value1&param2=value2 when your code runs. But what do you do with this variable?

params = "param1=" & value1 & "&param2=" & value2 ??

@FunThomas, i use this line  Shell "cmd /c start " & url, vbHide  and it opens the browser with the url link.
@braX, i make a macro with this code:
    Dim Url As String
    Url = "http://example.com/file.php?param1=value1&param2=value2"
    Shell "cmd /c start " & Url, vbHide
End Sub```
And i only get (https://example.com/file.php?param1=value1) at browser.
